# Complex series and the radius of convergence: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a+ib)^n\,\, a, b \in \mathbb{R}. $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Considering

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty(a+ib)^n,\quad a, b \in \mathbb{R}.
> $$

What constraints are required on the values of $a$ and $b$ to guarantee the convergence of the series?

How do I find the radius of convergence for this series?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  Please post the question in the question, not a link that everyone has to go through.  Cheers!

Comment: Did you try the Ratio Test?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall that the geometric series has a radius of convergence equal to $1$,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac1{1-z},\qquad |z|<1.
$$
This may be seen by using the standard identity:
$$
1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^N=\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z}, \quad z \neq 1,
$$ which, as $N \to \infty$, converges *if and only if* $|z|<1$.

Comment: Hm, perhaps the OP wants to know why it holds for $z\in\mathbb C$, which shouldn't be too hard to explain.

Comment: @Cushman See that $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}<1\implies a^2+b^2<1$

Comment: @Cushman Observe that $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Cushman The sum of the squares must be less than $1$.  So yes.

Comment: So the domain of convergence is the open disk of radius 1 centered at $(0,0)$: $D(0,1)=\left\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\,a^2+b^2<1\right\}.$

Comment: For the sake of exposition, polar coordinates may help: $a+ib = r e^{i\theta}$ with $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\lvert e^{i\theta}\rvert=1$, so the series $\sum_n (r e^{i\theta})^n$ converges iff $\lvert re^{i\theta}\lvert < 1$.